# Sqoop export data from voltdb

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, voltdb

I'm trying to import data into hive from a votldb table, here is the command I'm using

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:voltdb://<my_host>:<port> --driver org.voltdb.jdbc.Driver --password <volt password> --username <volt user> --table <table name in voltdb> --hive-database <hive schema> --hive-overwrite --create-hive-table --hive-import
```

I'm getting following error

```
ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: org.voltdb.jdbc.Driver.DriverManager
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: org.voltdb.jdbc.Driver.DriverManager
```

..........

I have placed voltdb jdbc jar file in '/var/lib/sqoop/'

my sqoop version is '1.4.5.2.2.6.3-1'

has anyone succeed in exporting table from voltdb to hive?

Answer (score 1):

I work for VoltDB.  VoltDB has an export connector for HTTP, which should be configured for WebHDFS, and then you can use Pig or Hive commands to periodically harvest the data from the export folder(s) in HDFS and load into Hive tables.

There is sample code for this in the VoltDB blog post [Integrating VoltDB into the Hadoop ecosystem with Hive and Pig](https://voltdb.com/blog/integrating-voltdb-hadoop-ecosystem-hive-and-pig), and the export connector is documented in [Using VoltDB 15.7.2. Exporting to Hadoop via WebHDFS](https://docs.voltdb.com/UsingVoltDB/ExportToHttp.php#ExportHttpWebHdfs).

If you found any documents online from VoltDB describing integration with Hadoop using sqoop, they are out-dated.